# call external python script in same window

Tags: python, console, external

Im trying to call an external python script, and so far i was able to do so successfully using:

```
os.system("START fileNameHere")
```

However right now im running in the console, and i want the contents of the other python file to be shown in the same console. ATM it shows it in a separate console.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This outta do it.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('command', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    for line in p.stdout.readlines():
        print line,
retval = p.wait()
```

Comment: nope, doesnt work. The script opens in another separate window

Comment: @Larry, Works fine for me, what OS are are you using?

Comment: @Larry, Ok, Windows. The `START` command is listed as: "Enables a user to start a separate window in Windows from the Windows command line." Don't use it if you don't want the output to be in another window! Simply run `fileNameHere` and don't use `START`.

Comment: Great Stuff, that got it working (removing the START). Thanks